# Artifactory Filestore has root and artifactory user entries

Tags: artifactory

There are files in the filestore folder with owner as "artifactory" and "root". When I deploy any artifact, it takes the owner as "root" and the artifactory identifies the artifacts deployed with "artifactory" user. Also, in linux, the artifactory user has the following 4 types of privileges:

1. -rw-rw-r--
2. -rwxr-x-r-x
3. -rw-r-----
4. -rw-r--r--

Please help me understand that which permission should I give to change the "root" owned artifacts to "artifactory" owned ones?

I haven't tired anything yet on this

Answer (score 4):

With regards to your scenario, I would like to clarify more.

From JFrog [wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS): "When running Artifactory as a service, the installation script creates a user called Artifactory which must have run and execute permissions on the installation directory."

In case you are running Artifactory as a service, I recommend giving ownership for Artifactory and remove "root" using the following:

1. chown -R artifactory:artifactory /var/opt/jfrog/
2. chown -R artifactory:artifactory /opt/jfrog/

With that saying, please note that you may see different permissions for files in different directories in Artifactory. This is the desired behaviour as some of the files requires extra security e.g Access files. I personally do not recommend changing the actual permissions for the files.

I hope this clarifies further.